# nodejs cross-origin read blocking issue with image resources and canvas

Tags: node.js, express, cross-origin-read-blocking

I have a nodejs application were cors setup is done using cors package from expressjs.
**My cors setup code is :**

```
var whitelist = ['https://shajao.com', 'https://www.shajao.com'];
var corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
            callback(null, true)
        } else {
            callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
        }
    },
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Content-Length', 'X-Requested-With', 'Accept'],
    methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/')));
```

apis are called from an angular application which is getting server reponses perfectly. So cors is working nicely here. But image resources are getting blocked by cors.

**Url to visit if you want to see the problem :**
https://shajao.com/frames

**Sample image url:** https://api.shajao.com/uploads/frames/8cf9006f-0225-461b-a4f2-153737152274.png

[image: CORS Errors i am getting]

Answer (score -1):

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (**CORB**) is a new web platform security feature.

Ref : https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers

Try clearing browser's cache first.

If it doesn't work  you will have to set the correct "Content-Type" header for the response.

Comment: I added it. but not working. can you explain why i need to add api.shajao.com? cuz i am accessing it from sajao.com